# Looping through with JS to get info from HTML list on Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to get the data of property transactions from a site using Javascript on the Google Chrome console.

So far, I've figured out how to get the info in a property object for the first property using this code:

```
var property = [{}]

property[0]['Name']  = document.querySelector("#closed-deals-container > section > div > div.profile-recent-transactions.profile-recent-transactions--paginated > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.uc-listingCard-body > div.uc-listingCard-content > div > div.uc-listingCard-titles > a").innerText;

property[0]['City-State-Zip'] = document.querySelector("#closed-deals-container > section > div > div.profile-recent-transactions.profile-recent-transactions--paginated > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.uc-listingCard-body > div.uc-listingCard-content > div > div.uc-listingCard-titles > h2").innerText;

property[0]['Price'] = document.querySelector("#closed-deals-container > section > div > div.profile-recent-transactions.profile-recent-transactions--paginated > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.uc-listingCard-body > div.uc-listingCard-content > div > div.uc-listingCard--priceGrid-sm > div").innerText;

property[0]['Beds'] = document.querySelector("#closed-deals-container > section > div > div.profile-recent-transactions.profile-recent-transactions--paginated > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.uc-listingCard-body > div.uc-listingCard-content > div > div.uc-listingCard-subStats.checkable-undefined > div.uc-listingCard-subStat.uc-listingCard-subStat--beds").innerText;

property[0]['Baths'] = document.querySelector("#closed-deals-container > section > div > div.profile-recent-transactions.profile-recent-transactions--paginated > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.uc-listingCard-body > div.uc-listingCard-content > div > div.uc-listingCard-subStats.checkable-undefined > div.uc-listingCard-subStat.uc-listingCard-subStat--baths").innerText;
```

There are 26 other properties on the list, and I'd like to loop through all of them and put them in the property object. I think I need to do a for loop, but I am having trouble figuring out how to execute it.

UPDATE:

The code below solved most of the issue, but I'm having trouble getting all transactions since many are paginated. See here for an example where there are 14 tabs of transactions within the page. How can I get them all by extending the below code?

```
const list = [];

jQuery('div.uc-listingCard-content').each(function () {
const $this = jQuery(this);

list.push({
    'Name': $this.find('.uc-listingCard-titles > a').text().trim(),
    'City-State-Zip': $this.find('.uc-listingCard-titles > h2').text().trim(),
    'Price': $this.find('.uc-listingCard--priceGrid-sm > div').text().trim(),
    'Beds': $this.find('.uc-listingCard-subStat--beds').text().trim(),
    'Baths': $this.find('.uc-listingCard-subStat--baths').text().trim(),
});
```

});

console.log(list);

Answer (score 1):

you can use console.log by JSON.stringify()
for example:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6 }));
// expected output: "{"x":5,"y":6}"
```

and for your code:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(property))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like this using jQuery.

```
const list = [];

jQuery('div.uc-listingCard-content').each(function () {
    const $this = jQuery(this);

    list.push({
        'Name': $this.find('.uc-listingCard-titles > a').text().trim(),
        'City-State-Zip': $this.find('.uc-listingCard-titles > h2').text().trim(),
        'Price': $this.find('.uc-listingCard--priceGrid-sm > div').text().trim(),
        'Beds': $this.find('.uc-listingCard-subStat--beds').text().trim(),
        'Baths': $this.find('.uc-listingCard-subStat--baths').text().trim(),
    });

});

console.log(list);
```

Comment: This worked well, but now I'm realizing that I can't add transactions from the different tabs of transactions within the page. See here for an example: https://www.compass.com/agents/eric-altree/ There are 14 pages of "Past Transactions" and I'm wondering how to pull all of them (not just those on page 1).